# Colour Saturation/Desat in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, colors

My question is a pretty simple one:

If I code an image to display using standard HTML, is it possible to desaturate that image completely using on jQuery alone?

The idea would be to return to normal saturation once the user hovers over the image...

I know there's an experimental method using HTML5 Canvas , but for the time being I'd like to stay away from HTML5 :)

Comment: You might want to look at the [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/) library, which uses Canvas for non-IE browsers, but falls back to the proprietary filter in IE for desaturation... The example on that page specifically gives a demo of the desaturation feature of the library.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Will have a closer look into it... I briefly skimmed the contents before asking the question as I thought there might something else on the horizon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery alone? Not really. You need some method to manipulate the image data and there are only four methods I'm aware of:

- HTML5 Canvas (You said you didn't want it)
- Proprietary IE Filter (Internet Explorer only)
- SVG Filters applied via CSS (Currently Firefox-only according to my tests)
- Flash Applet (Overkill, heavy, and generally unpleasant.)

Matt Gibson's suggestion of [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/) is a good one if your only concern is compatibility or you could roll your own using some mixture of the aforementioned approaches.

Comment: Hi ssokolow, thanks for the reply. Your reply is exactly what I suspected - it is, as yet, something that isn't widely supported. I guess the closest to that would be jQuery allowance for opacity (which is a far cry from optimal). Anyhoooo, thanks for the time you took to answer my q - much appreciated!

Comment: I feel compelled to mention, if we're avoiding canvas, that the best bet would be to generate the desaturated image server side and swap the two images on hover. The canvas route is way more fun though.